# pdfpages inserting document name in the lower left of every page

Tags: pdfpages

I am currently having some issues with the `pdfpages` package. It seems to print the filename (twice - one with .pdf extension and one with .bb) at the bottom left of the included pdf and I cannot for the life of me get rid of it! Using `grffile` package gets rid of the name with the .bb extension, but the .pdf still remains...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{grffile}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}, offset=0 0, openright]{0 - UPEC2015}
\end{document}
```

What gives?

Generated output:
[image: I want to get rid of the stuff in the magenta rectangles]

P.S.: Forgot to mention that this is actually not present in the included pdf, but is generated at compilation for some reason...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The most probable cause for trouble is using filenames with spaces.

Comment: I get the expected result with `\includepdf[...]{"0 - UPEC2015"}`

Comment: Well I've tried everything - including adding ` " " ` marks, renaming the files to have no spaces...

Comment: I wanted to add that putting spaces in the filename also seems to have caused my included pdfs to be off-centre!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The most probable cause for trouble is using filenames with spaces. – egreg

This was exactly the case apparently. For some reason, my MWE still exhibited this issue when I renamed the file but after a few compilations it disappeared.

In my final document, I realized that the fact that my files to be included were under a subfolder which had a space in its name was causing the problem...

```
./My Publications/
```

therefore had the space removed. I see that spaces in file names are no joke!
Thanks for the help, egreg!

Comment: I have the same problem but I want to keep the spaces in my filename. What can I do?